# Как добавить данные(полученные в формате JSON) в Spinner(Android)?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, arraylist, android-spinner

Ответ от сервера получаю в таком виде:

> [{"time":"09:00"},{"time":"09:01"},{"time":"09:02"},{"time":"09:03"},{"time":"09:04"},{"time":"09:05"},{"time":"09:06"},{"time":"09:07"},{"time":"09:08"},{"time":"09:09"},{"time":"09:10"},{"time":"09:11"}]

Все это добро пытаюсь запихать в обыкновенный Spinner, но никак не получается.
Подскажите пожалуйста люди добрые, как это делается правильно.

Вот, что получилось у меня:

```
public class GetTime extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public Context context;

    public GetTime(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlTime);

        try {
            httpResponseTime = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            StringHolderTime = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponseTime.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(StringHolderTime);

            Log.i("MyLOG", "GetTime.doInBackground(): " + jsonArray.length());

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String tim = jsonObject.getString("time");
                list.add(tim);
            }

            Log.i("MyLOG", "GetTime.doInBackground(): " + list);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RecordActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
```

> I/MyLOG: GetTime.doInBackground(): 12
>   I/MyLOG: GetTime.doInBackground(): [09:01, 09:02, 09:03, 09:04, 09:05, 09:06,
>   09:07, 09:08, 09:09, 09:10, 09:11, 09:12]

А Spinner пустой.

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос таким способом.

```
public class GetTime extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ArrayList<String> list;

    public Context context;

    public GetTime(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        list=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlTime);

        try {
            httpResponseTime = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            StringHolderTime = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponseTime.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(StringHolderTime);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                list.add(jsonObject.getString("time"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listItems.addAll(list);

        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(RecordActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
```